# What is missing in "as promised?"

Tags: phrases

You might say, "As promised, I am sending you a sample of our product."
The phrase "as promised" seems to lack something. What would be a complete sentence? Would it be "as I promised" or "as was promised?"

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is complete as it stands. It is common in business letters to begin sentences with introductions such as:

> As indicated
>
> As agreed
>
> As requested

These will generally be followed by a main clause such as:

> I am/we are sending you......

Such introductions are used to mean:

> As I/we agreed/promised/ etc

but it's not necessary to include the pronoun. It's understood.

Other typical examples of ways to introduce such letters are:

> With reference to your letter, I…"
>
> In response to your letter, I can confirm…"
>
> With regard to your memo, I…"

(http://www.english-at-home.com)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, 'as promised' is used as an adjunct (an adverbial (?) explanatory supplement). Nothing missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as an abbreviated version of 'as I promised I would,...' 
https://www.gymglish.com/en/english-translation/as-promised

> Definition
>
> As promised, (here is the report): As I promised you, as I assured
>   you, (here is the report)
>  idiom 
> Examples
>
> "As promised, here's the finance report I was telling you about."
>  "As
>   promised, here are the guidelines regarding the Outback Cologne
>   rebranding project"